# What is the difference between Maximal and Maximum Cliques

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Hardly I can not find the clear differences between Maximal and Maximum Cliques,
As I think Maximal means a graph can not be extended to connect more edges , means each node is connected with all other nodes, but is Maximum means at least a graph should be connected to other graph ?
any suggestion please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maximum means that there is no larger clique in the graph.  Maximal mean that the given clique cannot be extended to a larger one.

As an example, consider $G=K_{3}\cup K_{4}$ the disjoint union of two cliques.  The size of the largest clique in the graph is $4$ and the $K_4$ is a maximum sized clique.  The $K_{3}$ is maximal, meaning that if you add any other vertex in $G$ to the $K_{3}$ you no longer have a clique.  But it is not maximum since the size of it is $3<4$.

Comment: @user253008, no problem.  I got these backwards all the time for a long time (and still doubt myself periodically).

Comment: Yah, you are right, But if we add a node to K3, you said we will no longer have a clique so what then we have in this case?. and why Finding the maximum clique in a graph is NP-hard  Problem ?

Comment: @user253008, Finding a maximal clique is not hard... add vertices one at a time until you can't.  Finding the largest possible clique is hard (not in this particular case).

Comment: OK, OK
Again please :But if we add a node to K3, you said we will no longer have a clique so what then we have in this case

Comment: Can someone give me an example about non-maximal clique ? please and why ?

Comment: @user253008, if you consider any 3 vertices in the $K_{4}$ they form a non-maximal clique because there is another vertex that you can add and make a larger clique.